# How to find difference between parent domain and top domain (iframe) to overcome Cross frame scripting

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss, xfs

For example, I have a website called www.example.com which is a parent domain.
I am using frames inside it. Inside the frame, I am calling www.mail.example.com

I need to check whether mail.example.com(URL inside iframe) is same domain in which google having...

This prevents cross frame scripting.
How to achieve it?

Modals I worked out..

```
if (window.document.domain != top.document.domain) {   
   SWGuardianWindowOpen("http://google.com","_self","");
  }
```

Another:

```
if (self != top)
{
//redirect to the google.com
}


if (parent && parent.frames && parent.frames.length>0)
```

But these are not helpful...

Comment: Please use `example.com` / `example.net` / `example.org` for examples instead of real sites run by other people.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript hacks if you want to prevent non-same origin pages from embedding your website.

Simply add the following tag to the `<head>` of your HTML document (example: http://jsfiddle.net/b28CK/show/):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="SAMEORIGIN">
```

If you're allowed to modify the response headers of your server, you can also add the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` response header to achieve the same effect.

If you want to use JavaScript to detect the parent origin(s), then you can use `location.ancestorOrigins` to find out the list of parent origin(s). This only works in Webkit and Chromium-based browsers though.

Comment: Can you please show sample for location.ancestorOrigins ?

Comment: @Kumar It is just a list of origins (ie scheme://host, eg `http://example.com`), starting from the parent frame up to the top frame. Use a for loop to enumerate the list, eg `var origins = location.ancestorOrigins; for (var i=0; i<origins.length; ++i) { alert(origins[i]); }`